# what 2 & 3 mean in this and how can i change them CvMat* rot = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_32FC1)

Tags: image, image-manipulation, opencv

What do 2 & 3 mean in this and how can I change them?

```
CvMat* rot = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_32FC1)
```

When I change these two values I get an openCV GUI error handler.

size of input arguments do not match()

in function cvConvertScale.\cxconvert.cpp(1601)

I want to understand what that means

#### Update:

The code is:

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
int main()
{
    CvMat* rot = cvCreateMat(2,3,CV_32FC1);
    IplImage *src, *dst;
    src=cvLoadImage("doda.jpg");
//  make acopy of gray image(src)
    dst = cvCloneImage( src );
    dst->origin = src->origin;
// make dstof zeros 
    cvZero( dst );
// Compute rotation matrix
    double x=0.0;
// loop to get rotation from 0 to 360 by 4 press on anykey
    for(int i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        CvPoint2D32f center = cvPoint2D32f(src->width/2,src->height/2);
        double angle = 0+x;
        double scale = 0.6;
        cv2DRotationMatrix( center, angle, scale, rot );
// Do the transformation
        cvWarpAffine( src, dst, rot);
        cvNamedWindow( "Affine_Transform", 1 );
        cvShowImage( "Affine_Transform", dst );
        if (i<=4)
            x=x+90.0;
        else
            x=0.0;
        cvWaitKey();
    }
    cvReleaseImage( &dst );
    cvReleaseMat( &rot );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 and 3 are the row and column counts of the matrix you're creating.

From [Introduction to programming with OpenCV](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html#SECTION00042000000000000000):

Allocate a matrix:

> ```
> CvMat* cvCreateMat(int rows, int cols, int type);
> ```
>
> `type`: Type of the matrix elements. Specified in form
>    `CV_<bit_depth>(S|U|F)C<number_of_channels>`.  E.g.: `CV_8UC1` means an
>    8-bit unsigned single-channel matrix, `CV_32SC2` means a 32-bit signed
>    matrix with two channels.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
>  CvMat* M = cvCreateMat(4,4,CV_32FC1);
> ```

Changing them is as simple as substituting different values. But I guess you should already know that.

Answer (score 0):

2 = number of rows and 3 = number of columns in your matrix, `rot`.

Can you post the entire code? Or maybe tell us what you want to achieve? Are you trying to rotate an image?

Also, I'd recommend upgrading to [OpenCV 2.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/) which has a C++ interface. With the new version, you can extensively use the Mat class which handles everything (matrices,images,etc.) and makes things much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error using any other shape than 2x3 because it is then meaningless for opencv when you use `rot` for rotation.

Take a look at [Jacob's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278414/rotating-an-image-in-c-c/2278430#2278430).
He describes the rotation matrix components in details.