# Rotating an image in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, rotation

I need code for rotating an image in C++ which functions like imrotate function of matlab.
Please suggest a good link. Or if someone can provide the code for imrotate.

Or at least please explain the algorithm.

Its not a homework. I need this code for my project. And we can use any external library or code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[OpenCV2.0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-win/2.0/OpenCV-2.0.0a-win32.exe/download) has several computer vision and image processing tools. Specifically [warpAffine](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html?highlight=warp#warpAffine) (by defining the rotation matrix) will solve your problem with rotating an image.

The 2x3 transformation matrix mentioned in the documentation is as follows:
[image]

where θ is the angle of rotation and t<sub>x</sub> and t<sub>y</sub> is the translation along the *x* and *y* axes respectively.

You can get the source code [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide).

Also, OpenCV2.0 has *many* MATLAB-esque functions like `imread`, etc.

Comment: (+1)My friend uses this lib and loves it Look here http://ashish-newday.blogspot.com/2009/12/mouse-cursor-position-control-using-our.html

Comment: But there is no image warpImage in openCV

Comment: How should I define rotation matrix?

Comment: OpenCV asks for a 2x3 transformation matrix which I've included in my answer

Comment: Cool!! Thanks for the answer, BTY I also got this useful link:http://www.discover.uottawa.ca/~qchen/my_presentations/A%20Basic%20Introduction%20to%20OpenCV%20for%20Image%20Processing.pdf

Comment: Yes, that seems like a nice tutorial but it explains OpenCV with the old `IplImage*`. Don't forget to start using OpenCV2.0's new `Mat` class - it makes your code *much* cleaner!

Comment: The code for OpenCV is now in Git: git://code.opencv.org/opencv.git

Answer (score 3):

[Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick%2B%2B/) can help you. Read [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/tutorial/Magick++_tutorial.pdf) PDF and search for rotate.

Answer (score 1):

[Check](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/specialeffects/article.php/c1743) this hope it helps .

Other questions on stack overflow on the [same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299267/image-scaling-and-rotating-in-c-c) experts opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way of accomplishing this in C++, short of writing your own function for manipulating binary data, which yields other problems like "How do I decompress a jpg/png in C++?"

Your best bet is a 3rd party graphics library such as [libSDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: The question is a perfectly valid way to ask for a library that's linkable from C++.

Comment: ... I believe I linked him to a linkable library?

Answer (score 0):

[libgd](http://www.libgd.org/Main_Page) has image rotation functions.