# OpenCV: how to rotate IplImage?

Tags: image-manipulation, opencv

I need to rotate an image by very small angle, like 1-5 degrees. Does **OpenCV** provide simple way of doing that? From reading docs i can assume that *getAffineTransform()* should be involved, but there is no direct example of doing something like:

```
IplImage *rotateImage( IplImage *source, double angle);
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If you use OpenCV > 2.0 it is as easy as

```
using namespace cv;

Mat rotateImage(const Mat& source, double angle)
{
    Point2f src_center(source.cols/2.0F, source.rows/2.0F);
    Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);
    Mat dst;
    warpAffine(source, dst, rot_mat, source.size());
    return dst;
}
```

**Note:** angle is in degrees, not radians.

See the C++ interface documentation for more details and adapt as you need:

- [getRotationMatrix](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html?highlight=rotationmatrix#getRotationMatrix2D)
- [warpAffine](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/geometric_image_transformations.html?highlight=warpaffine#warpAffine)

Answer (score 5):

**Edit: To down voter: Please comment the reason for down voting a tried and tested code?**

```
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"
#include "math.h"
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    IplImage* src = cvLoadImage("lena.jpg", 1);    
    IplImage* dst = cvCloneImage( src );

    int delta = 1;
    int angle = 0;
    int opt = 1;   // 1： rotate & zoom
               // 0:  rotate only
    double factor;
    cvNamedWindow("src", 1);
    cvShowImage("src", src);

    for(;;)
    {
    float m[6];
    CvMat M = cvMat(2, 3, CV_32F, m);
    int w = src->width;
    int h = src->height;

    if(opt)  
        factor = (cos(angle*CV_PI/180.) + 1.05) * 2;
    else 
        factor = 1;
    m[0] = (float)(factor*cos(-angle*2*CV_PI/180.));
    m[1] = (float)(factor*sin(-angle*2*CV_PI/180.));
    m[3] = -m[1];
    m[4] = m[0];
    m[2] = w*0.5f;  
    m[5] = h*0.5f;  

    cvGetQuadrangleSubPix( src, dst, &M);
    cvNamedWindow("dst", 1);
    cvShowImage("dst", dst);
    if( cvWaitKey(1) == 27 )
        break;
    angle =(int)(angle + delta) % 360;
    }     
    return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**: See the following code for rotation using warpaffine
https://code.google.com/p/opencvjp-sample/source/browse/trunk/cpp/affine2_cpp.cpp?r=48

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

using namespace cv;

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  // (1)load a specified file as a 3-channel color image,
  //    set its ROI, and allocate a destination image
  const string imagename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "../image/building.png";
  Mat src_img = imread(imagename);
  if(!src_img.data)
    return -1;
  Mat dst_img = src_img.clone();

  // (2)set ROI
  Rect roi_rect(cvRound(src_img.cols*0.25), cvRound(src_img.rows*0.25), cvRound(src_img.cols*0.5), cvRound(src_img.rows*0.5));
  Mat src_roi(src_img, roi_rect);
  Mat dst_roi(dst_img, roi_rect);

  // (2)With specified three parameters (angle, rotation center, scale)
  //    calculate an affine transformation matrix by cv2DRotationMatrix
  double angle = -45.0, scale = 1.0;
  Point2d center(src_roi.cols*0.5, src_roi.rows*0.5);
  const Mat affine_matrix = getRotationMatrix2D( center, angle, scale );

  // (3)rotate the image by warpAffine taking the affine matrix
  warpAffine(src_roi, dst_roi, affine_matrix, dst_roi.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(255));

  // (4)show source and destination images with a rectangle indicating ROI
  rectangle(src_img, roi_rect.tl(), roi_rect.br(), Scalar(255,0,255), 2);

  namedWindow("src", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  namedWindow("dst", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("src", src_img);
  imshow("dst", dst_img);
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check my answer to a similar problem:

[Rotating an image in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2278414/rotating-an-image-in-c-c/2278430#2278430)

Essentially, use [cvWarpAffine](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/geometric_image_transformations.html?highlight=cvwarpaffine#cvWarpAffine) - I've described how to get the 2x3 transformation matrix from the angle in my previous answer.

Answer (score 3):

Updating full answer for OpenCV 2.4 and up

```
// ROTATE p by R
/**
 * Rotate p according to rotation matrix (from getRotationMatrix2D()) R
 * @param R     Rotation matrix from getRotationMatrix2D()
 * @param p     Point2f to rotate
 * @return      Returns rotated coordinates in a Point2f
 */
Point2f rotPoint(const Mat &R, const Point2f &p)
{
    Point2f rp;
    rp.x = (float)(R.at<double>(0,0)*p.x + R.at<double>(0,1)*p.y + R.at<double>(0,2));
    rp.y = (float)(R.at<double>(1,0)*p.x + R.at<double>(1,1)*p.y + R.at<double>(1,2));
    return rp;
}

//COMPUTE THE SIZE NEEDED TO LOSSLESSLY STORE A ROTATED IMAGE
/**
 * Return the size needed to contain bounding box bb when rotated by R
 * @param R     Rotation matrix from getRotationMatrix2D()
 * @param bb    bounding box rectangle to be rotated by R
 * @return      Size of image(width,height) that will compleley contain bb when rotated by R
 */
Size rotatedImageBB(const Mat &R, const Rect &bb)
{
    //Rotate the rectangle coordinates
    vector<Point2f> rp;
    rp.push_back(rotPoint(R,Point2f(bb.x,bb.y)));
    rp.push_back(rotPoint(R,Point2f(bb.x + bb.width,bb.y)));
    rp.push_back(rotPoint(R,Point2f(bb.x + bb.width,bb.y+bb.height)));
    rp.push_back(rotPoint(R,Point2f(bb.x,bb.y+bb.height)));
    //Find float bounding box r
    float x = rp[0].x;
    float y = rp[0].y;
    float left = x, right = x, up = y, down = y;
    for(int i = 1; i<4; ++i)
    {
        x = rp[i].x;
        y = rp[i].y;
        if(left > x) left = x;
        if(right < x) right = x;
        if(up > y) up = y;
        if(down < y) down = y;
    }
    int w = (int)(right - left + 0.5);
    int h = (int)(down - up + 0.5);
    return Size(w,h);
}

/**
 * Rotate region "fromroi" in image "fromI" a total of "angle" degrees and put it in "toI" if toI exists.
 * If toI doesn't exist, create it such that it will hold the entire rotated region. Return toI, rotated imge
 *   This will put the rotated fromroi piece of fromI into the toI image
 *
 * @param fromI     Input image to be rotated
 * @param toI       Output image if provided, (else if &toI = 0, it will create a Mat fill it with the rotated image roi, and return it).
 * @param fromroi   roi region in fromI to be rotated.
 * @param angle     Angle in degrees to rotate
 * @return          Rotated image (you can ignore if you passed in toI
 */
Mat rotateImage(const Mat &fromI, Mat *toI, const Rect &fromroi, double angle)
{
    //CHECK STUFF
    // you should protect against bad parameters here ... omitted ...

    //MAKE OR GET THE "toI" MATRIX
    Point2f cx((float)fromroi.x + (float)fromroi.width/2.0,fromroi.y +
               (float)fromroi.height/2.0);
    Mat R = getRotationMatrix2D(cx,angle,1);
    Mat rotI;
    if(toI)
        rotI = *toI;
    else
    {
        Size rs = rotatedImageBB(R, fromroi);
        rotI.create(rs,fromI.type());
    }

    //ADJUST FOR SHIFTS
    double wdiff = (double)((cx.x - rotI.cols/2.0));
    double hdiff = (double)((cx.y - rotI.rows/2.0));
    R.at<double>(0,2) -= wdiff; //Adjust the rotation point to the middle of the dst image
    R.at<double>(1,2) -= hdiff;

    //ROTATE
    warpAffine(fromI, rotI, R, rotI.size(), INTER_CUBIC, BORDER_CONSTANT, Scalar::all(0)); 

    //& OUT
    return(rotI);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IplImage* rotate(double angle, float centreX, float centreY, IplImage* src, bool crop)
{
    int w=src->width;
    int h=src->height;

        CvPoint2D32f centre;
        centre.x = centreX;
        centre.y = centreY;

        CvMat* warp_mat = cvCreateMat(2, 3, CV_32FC1);

        cv2DRotationMatrix(centre, angle, 1.0, warp_mat);

        double m11= cvmGet(warp_mat,0,0);
        double m12= cvmGet(warp_mat,0,1);
        double m13= cvmGet(warp_mat,0,2);
        double m21= cvmGet(warp_mat,1,0);
        double m22= cvmGet(warp_mat,1,1);
        double m23= cvmGet(warp_mat,1,2);
        double m31= 0;
        double m32= 0;
        double m33= 1;
        double x=0;
        double y=0;
        double u0= (m11*x + m12*y + m13)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        double v0= (m21*x + m22*y + m23)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        x=w;
        y=0;
        double u1= (m11*x + m12*y + m13)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        double v1= (m21*x + m22*y + m23)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        x=0;
        y=h;
        double u2= (m11*x + m12*y + m13)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        double v2= (m21*x + m22*y + m23)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        x=w;
        y=h;
        double u3= (m11*x + m12*y + m13)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);
        double v3= (m21*x + m22*y + m23)/(m31*x + m32*y + m33);

        int left= MAX(MAX(u0,u2),0);
        int right= MIN(MIN(u1,u3),w);
        int top= MAX(MAX(v0,v1),0);
        int bottom= MIN(MIN(v2,v3),h);

        ASSERT(left<right&&top<bottom); // throw message?
        if (left<right&&top<bottom)
        {
            IplImage* dst= cvCreateImage( cvGetSize(src), IPL_DEPTH_8U, src->nChannels);
            cvWarpAffine(src, dst, warp_mat/*, CV_INTER_LINEAR + CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0)*/);

            if (crop) // crop and resize to initial size
            {
                IplImage* dst_crop= cvCreateImage(cvSize(right-left, bottom-top), IPL_DEPTH_8U, src->nChannels);
                cvSetImageROI(dst,cvRect(left,top,right-left,bottom-top));
                cvCopy(dst,dst_crop);
                cvReleaseImage(&dst);
                cvReleaseMat(&warp_mat);
                //ver1 
                //return dst_crop;
                // ver2 resize
                IplImage* out= cvCreateImage(cvSize(w, h), IPL_DEPTH_8U, src->nChannels);
                cvResize(dst_crop,out);
                cvReleaseImage(&dst_crop);
                return out;
            }
            else
            {
                /*cvLine( dst, cvPoint(left,top),cvPoint(left, bottom), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0) ,1,CV_AA);
                cvLine( dst, cvPoint(right,top),cvPoint(right, bottom), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0) ,1,CV_AA);
                cvLine( dst, cvPoint(left,top),cvPoint(right, top), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0) ,1,CV_AA);
                cvLine( dst, cvPoint(left,bottom),cvPoint(right, bottom), cvScalar(0, 0, 255, 0) ,1,CV_AA);*/
                cvReleaseMat(&warp_mat);
                return dst;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return NULL;  //assert?
        }
}
```

Comment: Give a reason for downvoting! 'It says the answer is not useful'. Why not?