# Concatenate OpenCV Mat and a single value

Tags: c++, opencv, concatenation, mat

I'm using OpenCV 3.2.

Let's suppose I have a `3 x 1` Mat:

```
cv::Mat foo = (cv::Mat_<float>(3,1) << 0, 1, 2);
```

Now I want to concatenate a single value to `foo`, and then having a resulting `4 x 1` Mat.

A simple solution would be:

```
cv::Mat bar = (cv::Mat_<float>(4,1) << foo.at<float>(0,0),
                                       foo.at<float>(1,0),
                                       foo.at<float>(2,0),
                                       3);
```

But this solution overfits to the problem dimensions. Of course, I can generalize it by looping all the values of an `n x 1` Mat, resulting in an `n+1 x 1`.

What I'm looking for is a smarter solution that takes advantage of OpenCV syntax, and directly returns the concatenation of a single-column Mat and a single value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8839769/opencv-add-columns-to-a-matrix

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I already saw this post, but I didn't like it because you have to add the single value to a container to make it compatible with `hconcat` method. I am looking for a specific syntax that offers the concatenation of a Mat and a single value.

Comment: What about [`push_back`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back)?

Comment: @DanMašek You've done the work, write it up for some points :-)

Comment: @MarkSetchell OK, although I just read the documentation. But if you insist... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck. `cv::Mat` provides member function [`push_back`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back) which

> adds elements to the bottom of the matrix

Furthermore,

> The methods add one or more elements to the bottom of the matrix. They emulate the corresponding method of the STL vector class. ...

Since your `Mat` has a single column, you can just simply add scalar values, you just have to make sure the type matches the data type of the `Mat`. In you case you can add `float`s directly, but anything else you need to cast to `float` explicitly before adding.

If you had a `Mat` with a single row, and wanted to add a column, it would be a little more complicated. You're need to use [`reshape`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-reshape) before and after the `push_back`. However, to quote the documentation

> No data is copied. That is, this is an O(1) operation.

If you need to do this often, then it's trivial to wrap it in an inline function.

### Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    // Adding rows

    cv::Mat foo = (cv::Mat_<float>(3, 1) << 0, 1, 2);
    std::cout << foo << "\n";

    foo.push_back(3.0f);
    std::cout << foo << "\n";

    foo.push_back(static_cast<float>(4)); // Need to make sure the type matches!
    std::cout << foo << "\n";

    // -----

    // Adding columns

    cv::Mat bar = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 0, 1, 2);
    std::cout << bar << "\n";

    // push_back needs to add a full row so reshapes are needed (but cheap)
    bar = bar.reshape(1, bar.cols);
    bar.push_back(3.0f);
    bar = bar.reshape(bar.rows);
    std::cout << bar << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

### Console Output

```
[0;
 1;
 2]
[0;
 1;
 2;
 3]
[0;
 1;
 2;
 3;
 4]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Nicely explained! And you go the extra mile with adding columns 