# How can an image be rotated with OpenCV with a custom colour for the gaps around the edge?

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to rotate an image in OpenCV (I'm currently doing it this way [image manipulation SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2289690/opencv-how-to-rotate-iplimage/#2300459)) but would like to specify the colour used to fill the gaps created by the rotation - by default, it's black (see below)

[image]

How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the [official doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=affine#warpaffine):

```
C: void cvWarpAffine(const CvArr* src, CvArr* dst, const CvMat* map_matrix, int flags=CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, CvScalar fillval=cvScalarAll(0) )
```

where

`CvScalar fillval=cvScalarAll(0)` specifies the fill color of the "gap".

Just specify the `fillval` with a color scalar when calling this function.

Comment: Why are you referencing the obsolete C API, instead of C++?

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! As @jnovacho pointed out, you are using the old C API - but the same argument still exists in cv2: `void warpAffine(InputArray src, OutputArray dst, InputArray M, Size dsize, int flags=INTER_LINEAR, int borderMode=BORDER_CONSTANT, const Scalar& borderValue=Scalar()`